# How many standard deviations does a point lie from a 2D Gaussian mean?

Tags: probability, statistics, standard-deviation, gaussian-integral, fuzzy-logic

I am trying to find a method to calculate how far a point lies from the mean of a 2D Gaussian in terms of standard deviations. I have drawn a diagram to demonstrate my problem.

[Diagram of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEU6q.png)

I know the position of the mean, the position of the point and the 2x2 Covariance matrix of the Gaussian.

I am currently using the Gaussian Distribution function to determine the (z-axis) height of the Gaussian curve at the given point, but a standard deviation measurement in the x/y plane is far more valuable to me.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is precisely the [Mahalanobis distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance) of an observation.

Comment: This is exactly what I am after, thank you!